# Failed to get Credential in Azure Automation Runbook

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-automation

I am trying to do a basic database operation using azure runbook (Code below). It is failing when I test it on Azure cloud. Error - [image]

By doing a line by line execution, I found out that this error is caused by `Get-AutomationPSCredential`. However, the entire code is working fine when I run it from PowerShell ISE in my local system.

```
workflow sqlrunbook()
{
    $SqlServer = "devserver001.database.windows.net"
    $Database = "devdb001"

    $SqlCredential = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name 'SqlCredentialAsset'

    # Get the username and password from the SQL Credential
    $SqlUsername = $SqlCredential.GetNetworkCredential().UserName
    $SqlPassword = $SqlCredential.GetNetworkCredential().Password

    inlinescript
    {        
        $Conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Server=tcp:$using:SqlServer;Database=$using:Database;User ID=$using:SqlUsername;Password=$using:SqlPassword;")

        $Cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("insert into TestTable(ID) values(1)", $Conn)

        $Cmd.CommandTimeout=120

        $Conn.Open()        
        $Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        $Conn.Close()
    }
}
sqlrunbook
```

Can you please let me know if I missed anyting while creating credential or should I enable any configuration to test this run book on Azure cloud? Thank in advance.[image]

Comment: Your code looks correct (assuming your Automation account does have a Credential asset named "SqlCredentialAsset"). There is no additional configuration required to enable this. The error looks like an intermittent infrastructural issue. What if you try running this again?

Comment: Tried again, no luck.

Comment: Are you certain the error is reported by Get-AutomationPSCredential? What if you remove everything else from your runbook and leave just this line?If this keeps failing, please try on a different Automation account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
Get-AzureAutomationCredential -AutomationAccountName "Contoso17" -Name "MyCredential"
```

you can check this link also:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-credentials

Comment: I tried this method, but received this error "Get-AzureAutomationCredential : No default subscription has been designated. Use Select-AzureSubscription -Default 
<subscriptionName> to set the default subscription."